# Access { get set } property methods, WITHOUT reflection

Tags: .net

I want to be able to access the `void set_PropertyName(var value)` and `var get_Property()` methods of a Property.

Is there any way of doing this **WITHOUT** reflection?
And without getting [`Compiler Error CS0571`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28CS0571%29%3bk%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29&rd=true).

**EDIT**
By without reflection I meant without the overhead of what Reflection does (not just having to write the code), since this is code that needs to be run lots of times i want it without the overhead of reflection.
dynamic also uses reflection under the covers unfortunately.

It seems this might be possible with c++.net but not with the other languages (though i can't tell because my installation of C++ is stuffed up).

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Perhaps `dynamic dynamicObject = notSoDynamicObject; int z = dynamicObject.get_Property();`

Comment: What are you trying to do?  (Replace the implementations at runtime, dynamically invoke a property, inspect the types or something else entirely?)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273589/dynamic-object-property-populator-without-reflection

Comment: @ta.speot.is I did try, though unfortunately it didn't work. Plus i'm fairly certain that dynamic uses reflection under the covers.

Comment: * since this is code that needs to be run lots of times i want it without the overhead of reflection. dynamic also uses reflection under the covers unfortunately.* Well I think those compiled expressions are what you want. Assuming that the property does not change (i.e. you might have 10 properties that need to be called 10,000 times each not 100,000 properties that need to be called once)

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible if you use the [callbyname](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.callbyname.aspx) available from the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace

ex;

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new Test();
            Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CallByName(test, "property" ,CallType.Set, 1);
            Console.WriteLine(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CallByName(test, "property", CallType.Get));
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public int property { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MauricioScheffer ,under the hood, yes but... you don't have to do all the "work"

Comment: I feel OP wasn't clear enough in specifying `reflection` as in `Without System.Reflection` or `without using reflection`.

Comment: Yeah i meant without the overhead reflection being called, not the actual reflection itself.

Comment: [There are a couple of tricks you can pull to compile `Expression`s that provide pretty good performance](http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2012/2/4/reflection-vs-compiled-expressions-vs-delegates-performance-comparision).

Comment: @ta.speot.is Thanks i didn't know about Expression's, It still won't give me what i'm looking for in this specific instance, that they could be useful none the less.